# No Minidumps in folder

Tags: windows-7, bsod, minidumps

I'm getting a Memory_Management BSOD and its getting annoying. I'm 90% sure that my settings are correct for mini dumps but I'm not getting any.

Settings:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling shadow cache in bios

Comment: In `regedit`, is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl` the value `CrashDumpEnabled` set to `3`? If not, set it to `3` and reboot.

Comment: It's set to 3. And how do I change the shadow cache?